# Uploaded file does not have same SHA-256 checksum as local copy

Tags: sharepoint-rest-api

I have used SharePoint for a month or so now and have recently noticed the following behaviour:

If I upload, say, a pdf file to SharePoint and then download it again the SHA-256 checksum of the two files is the same as expected. This is also true of .png, .odt and .txt files.

However if I do the same thing with .docx or .xlsx files then the SHA-256 checksum of the two files is different!

I have also developed a perl script using REST that can upload and download files to SharePoint and have noticed the same behaviour. This causes problems because, effectively, the local file, in general, is NOT the same file on SharePoint.

Answer (score 2):

SharePoint performs property demotion and promotion as files enter it. This modifies the metadata of the file itself (you can see various SPO-related properties when you look at the Word document properties from within Word itself).

For SPO, I do not believe it is currently possible to disable this.

Comment: Thanks for the info, although I find it strange that some file types are "modified" and others are not.

Comment: Only files supported by SharePoint's parser will be altered, primarily Office documents. Office on the web plays no part in this as this functionality existed prior to OWA being a product in SharePoint Server 2007.

Comment: See https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/office/sharepoint-server/ms459891(v=office.15)#remarks for more details.

Comment: Many thanks for your help on this Trevor

Comment: A fix for this seems to be here (haven't tried it as I have no admin rights): https://github.com/29039/29039s-useful-stuff/blob/main/m365-sharepoint-online-set-parserdisabled.md